# How to clean image for OCR - Opencv

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

I need to extract some informations from many documents like this one: [ImageRaw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZV1zy.jpg)
[Better image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvJHz.jpg)
The fixed data are in red, the variables are in black. I need to get the "N°", "Texte" & "Evolution" area.
In this example I want to get "84824 00" "E" and "00"

I tried to use this:

```
imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
imgThreshold1 = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(imgGray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_GAUSSIAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV, size, c)
_, imgThreshold2 = cv2.threshold(imgGray, level, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
```

I tried several value of size, c and k, but the result is bad. The most difficult part is seeing the red text. What advice can you give me?

Comment: For your use case, Is it possible to take pictures with better quality (higher resolution, better lighting conditions)?

Comment: I tried with better image, but cannot get a clean "EVOLUTION": https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvJHz.jpg

Comment: The image is still of low resolution and blurred. Not good conditions for free OCR libs. Which OCR package do you use? Can you share a minimal reproducible example that shows your issue? Did you read other posts on OCR for low contrast images and how to recognise single letters and digits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply contrast stretch the images dynamic range using Python/OpenCV with Skimage.

Input:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import skimage.exposure

# read the input
img = cv2.imread('fiche.jpg')

# stretch the dynamic range
stretch = skimage.exposure.rescale_intensity(img, in_range=(50,175), out_range=(0,255)).astype(np.uint8)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('fiche_stretched.jpg', stretch)

# show results
cv2.imshow('stretch', stretch)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it helps a lot. I'll also try to get better resolution. Thanks

Comment: If that helped, please consider giving it an up-vote